# How you explain that result?

Tags: implied-volatility, fama-french, quantitative, statistical-finance, volatility-smile

I'm reading this paper :
[What Does the Individual Option Volatility
Smirk Tell Us About Future Equity Returns?](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/article/abs/what-does-the-individual-option-volatility-smirk-tell-us-about-future-equity-returns/ECFD16BA9ACBDC8D577D1BD866FBEA72)
Yuhang Xing, Xiaoyan Zhang, and Rui Zhao∗
In section 2. A i found this equation: [image]
... And I don't understand how it comes up with this result, because if I compute: (8.43%-2.40%)x(-0.0061) it would be equal to: -0.0003678 and not as it says i.e. 5.52bp or 2.90% per year
The screenshoots from which take the values is:
[image]
and
[image]
Can someone explain me?! Help me please

Comment: Looks like a simple arithmetic mistake.

Comment: Since the [Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis) is a peer-reviewed journal, I suggest asking on https://pubpeer.com/